# Solution of linear algebraic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving, infinity

In addition to $x=0$, are $x=\infty$ and $x=-\infty$ solutions of $x=2x$ because $\infty=2\cdot\infty$ and $-\infty=-2\cdot\infty$?

Comment: Not in $\mathbb{R}$ since $\pm \infty$ are not real numbers.

Comment: Infinity is not a number

Comment: Not to mention, the problem of finding solutions of $x=2x$ can be rephrased as the finding the zeroes of the function $f(x)=2x-x$ by moving the both to the same side, i.e. the zeroes of the function $f(x)=x$.  $\infty$ is not considered a zero of that function when viewing it from a complex analysis point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're solving the problem in the extended real numbers, then yes, the set of solutions to $x = 2x$ is indeed $\{ 0, +\infty, -\infty\}$. Problems like this arise from time to time when computing limits in calculus, and sometimes the actual answer you're looking for really is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, so it's good to pay attention to this detail when the extended real numbers are applicable.

If you're just solving in the real numbers, however, then $0$ is the only solution. ($\pm \infty$ aren't real numbers, they're extended real numbers!)